# Select MySQL Data in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015

I want to login to the program using c#, with my username and password that's stored to the SQL Database in phpmyadmin.
This is what I have so far.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection connection;
            string server = "localhost";
            string database = "login";
            string uid = "root";
            string password = "";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
            database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";


            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    Form1 frm = new Form1(this);
                    frm.Show();
                    Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Database Connection Failed", "Epic Fail", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An Error Occured, Try again later.", "Epic Fail", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            }
        }
```

It connects to the database, however I don't want it to show the form1 Until both a valid Username and Password have been entered.
I'm guessing I need to use SELECT * FROM but I'm not exactly sure how to go about it.

Comment: The connection would fail if the credentials are incorrect and an exception would be thrown and thus `catch (Exception ex)` block would execute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this way to see if username and password match

```
MySqlCommand cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) from tbUser WHERE UserName = @username and password=@password";
command.Parameters.Add("@username", txtUserName.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@password", txtPassword.Text);
var count = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if(count>0)
    //Logged In
```

Just to say, if you use a query like

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) from tbUser WHERE UserName = '"+txtusernam +"'";
```

You will be open to SQL Injection

**Warning**

As Steve mentioned in comments Passwords in clear text are a vulnerability of the same magnitude of string concatenation

Comment: Just add a warning here. Passwords in clear text are a vulnerability of the same magnitude of string concatenation.

Comment: @Steve Thanks. I will add it to my answer

Comment: Thank you, and Passwords are hashed.

Comment: command.Parameters.Add has a red line under command.
Same for db.conn.CreateCommand, db.conn isn't recognized.
What should I be 'using'

Answer (score 1):

you make try this one

```
using(var con = new MysqlConnection{ ConnectionString = "your connection string " })
{
    using(var command = new MysqlCommand{ Connection = con })
    {
       con.Open();

       command.CommandText = @"SELECT level FROM userTable WHERE username=@username, password=@password";
       command.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text);
       command.AddWithValue("@password", txtpassword.Text);

       var strLevel = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();

       if(strLevel == DBNULL.Value || strLevel == Null)
       {
          MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password");
          return;
       }
       else
       {
          MessageBox.Show("Successfully login");
          hide(); // hide this form and show another form
       }

}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

use below Query

```
Select * from UsersTable Where Username='"+username+"' AND password='"+password+"'
```

Then you can make a if condition that if your query contain a result (rows) then users authenticated (exists in Table)

> Note:Select query may fetch multiple users having same userName and
>   password, its upto you to keep usersname unique in table

Comment: DO NOT TEACH STRING CONCATENATION, please.

Comment: Nothing against you of course. This problem is so diffuse that I feel really bad when I see an answer that use this approach. I can't remove the downvote now, but you can always delete the answer or fix the problem (but at this point your answer will be the same as the other one). Sorry.

Comment: No, I will not delete,It will play warning mark for others so that they avoid this approach,Thanks again

Comment: Uhm, not sure if the community has the same stand about this. We will see.

Comment: @Steve, every gentlemen will dislike spoon feeding,