# I having problems with a user-password coding example

Tags: c#, mysql, passwords

[Using this earlier question I need a bit of help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933496/select-mysql-data-in-c-sharp)

Using the second answer in the above link I had to update it for MySQL

```
 private void btLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            using (var con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString));
            {
                using (var command = new MySqlCommand(connection = con))
                {
                    con.Open();

                    command.CommandText = @"SELECT level FROM userTable WHERE user=@username, password=@password";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", lbUser.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", tbPassword.Text);

                    var strLevel = command.ExecuteScalar();

                    if (strLevel == DBNull.Value || strLevel == null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password");
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Successfully login");
                        Hide(); // hide this form and show another form
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Everything looks good BUT this

```
 using (var con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString));
            {
                using (var command = new MySqlCommand(connection = con))
                {
                    con.Open();
```

It says that con doesn't exist.  I don't know Using that well to see the problem.

Comment: I found the reason for the con didn't exits; there was a  ;  after the first  using.  However I now have this:  'using (var command = new MySqlCommand(connection = con))'   Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' to 'string' DPinBox2 C:\Users\de507\source\repos\DPinBox2\DPinBox2\LoginForm.cs 76 Active

Comment: Try `using (var command = new MySqlCommand(con))`.  I don't think you need `connection` variable anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter to the `MySqlCommand` constructor is the command text. It should work if you change your code to the following:

```cs
con.Open();
using (var command = new MySqlCommand())
{
    command.Connection = con;
    command.CommandText = @"SELECT level FROM userTable WHERE user=@username AND password=@password";
```

Comment: Thanks!  Had to play with it a little more but that was not caused by your suggested code.